# Facebook 5 messaging url scheme

Tags: ios, facebook

is there an ios URL scheme that can be used to open the facebook app (version 5.x) with the dialog that can be used to send a private message to given facebook id?

Answer (score 0):

[Page 9 should help](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-eu-11/Nitesh_Dhanjani/BlackHat_EU_2011_Dhanjani_Attacks_Against_Apples_iOS-WP.pdf)

[Handle Open Url](http://handleopenurl.com/) should also help in the general case

Answer (score -1):

you cant send the Private Message to any user using fb api, you can post message on his wall (Feed post).

Comment: I'm asking for a url scheme to open the facebook application, I'm not trying to send a private message in-app. I thought that was possible.

Comment: urlscheme is [fb + yourAppID] like fbXXXXXXXXXXXXX